# Blueimp jQuery File Upload permission issue with UploadHandler.php

Tags: jquery, permissions, blueimp

I'm struggeling for days by getting the upload of a picture done for my production side. On localhost everything works fine...of course it's localhost, but on production side it fails.
First of all...yes I set the permission for the "files"-folder to 755
When I run the upload-job by having the javascript-console active I get an "200 ok" and the progress-bar is expanding till 100%, so somehow data is uploaded. But once 100% is reached I get an failed response (still a "200 ok" in network output in javascript console).
When I click in the details of the FileUpload.php trace in the javascript-console I see a lot of warnings like:

- Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in **/www/htdocs//php/FileUpload/UploadHandler.php** on line **320**
- Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in **/www/htdocs/php/FileUpload/UploadHandler.php** on line **790**
  ...
  This I ignore, but now it gets strange...at the end of the traces I see following results:
- move_uploaded_file(/www/htdocs//php/FileUpload/files/img159.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in **/www/htdocs//php/FileUpload/UploadHandler.php** on line **1081**
- move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/php1aB0DW' to '/www/htdocs//php/FileUpload/files/img159.jpg' in **/www/htdocs//php/FileUpload/UploadHandler.php** on line **1081**
- filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for /www/htdocs//php/FileUpload/files/img159.jpg in **/www/htdocs//php/FileUpload/UploadHandler.php** on line **307**
- unlink(/www/htdocs//php/FileUpload/files/img159.jpg) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in **/www/htdocs//php/FileUpload/UploadHandler.php** on line **1100**
- Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www//php/FileUpload/UploadHandler.php:320) in **/www/htdocs//php/FileUpload/UploadHandler.php** on line **1130**

...the above message repeats several times...

- Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/htdocs//php/FileUpload/UploadHandler.php:320) in **/www/htdocs//php/FileUpload/UploadHandler.php** on line **1130**
  {"files":[{"name":"img159.jpg","size":false,"type":"image/jpeg","error":"File upload aborted","deleteUrl":"http/php/FileUpload/?file=img159.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"}]

As stated, I have set the permission of teh files-folder to "755"...so what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have designed a prestashop module with this library and second one is under development right now while i am typing this comment.
Tell me are you adding anything new to this library?

Comment: no...not added anything new to this library

Comment: Try by setting directory permission 777. If it will not work than we will solve it together. you can mail me at vipulhadiya@ymail.com

Comment: Hi, thanks for the offer. I tried with 777 and it works, but I'm not happy with this solution as I don't want to give write and execute permissions for my "files"-directory. As stated on blueimp-project page the permissions should be set to "755", which makes sense, but here I run into the described problem.

Comment: Okay, i am happy for now you have working code. Sure we will resolve your issue with 755 permission. Please mail me your complete process means when you get this error. Is there any pattern or every time you get these errors?

Comment: Hi Vipul, thanks a lot. I have send you an email with my traces and header-informations.

Comment: so...it seems that permission must be set to 777, which seems to be not logical. Is there anyone having an idea of what to do to be able to work with 755 permissions on files-folder (as described on blueimp-jQuery-file-upload project page)?